# Error while calling Java MVC View method in Lotus Notes Xpages button Click

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have MVC code pattern written in java build in Lotus Notes.
Wanted to call the java view in Lotus Notes Xpages to authenticate the app using oauth2.0 in lotus notes xpages.

The same SDK provided for .net i am able to execute need help in java xpages.

Method in JavaMVC

@RequestMapping("/connectToABC")
    public View connectToABC(Session session) throws NotesException {
return new RedirectView(oauth2Config.prepareUrl(scopes, redirectUri, csrf), true, true, false);
}

XPAGES

importPackage(com.abc.developer.sampleapp.oauth2.controller);

var obj = new OAuth2Controller();
obj.connectToABC(session);

Please help in authenticating in xpages with oauth2.0 client API

Answer (score 1):

If it's a standard Java API, working examples of that API are irrelevant. Look for working examples of any standard Java API, e.g. Apache POI. The questions you have on integration will be answered by that. Questions on using the API should be addressed by the Intuit API documentation.

One aspect to bear in mind is that the standard Java policy in Domino restricts quite a bit, particularly Java reflection. If the Intuit Java API uses Java reflection to convert JSON to Java objects and vice versa, you will need to amend the Java policy, use `AccessController.doPrivileged` to elevate permissions or possibly wrap such calls and the API in an OSGi plugin. But you'll need to try and, if necessary, investigate further to verify if you need to do that.

Comment: how do we work with API from vendor which have oauth 2.0 authentication in lotus notes. Would it possible if you can help me on skype.